# Dynamic Range Excel VBA: can you stock a cell range and then call it again with range function?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

I'm trying to use a for loop to draw a border around a series of ranges in my spreadsheet, except the size of the range is stocked in a variable. Here is my code:

```
    For i = 0 To 19
        Dim top_left, bottom_right As Range
        Set top_left = Range("G4").Offset(0, 2 * i)
        Set bottom_right = Range("H" & size).Offset(0, 2 * i)
        Worksheets(3).Range(top_left & ":" & bottom_left).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Next
```

Where `size` is the vertical length of my range starting from cell G4 downwards, and the width of my range is 2 cells (thus the 2*i in the offset of the For loop).

The error is on this line:

```
    Worksheets(3).Range(top_left & ":" & bottom_left).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
```

I've tried converting the ranges to Addresses or strings but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `Worksheets(3).Range(top_left.Address & ":" & bottom_left.Address)....` or `Worksheets(3).Range(top_left, bottom_left)...`

Comment: Try using `Range(top_left, bottom_left)`

Comment: Except you `Set bottom_right` but are trying to use `bottom_left`. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you've wrote "bottom_left" in the line with an error but "bottom_left" doesn't exist. I think you wanted to write "bottom_right", isn't it ?

Second, "top_left" and "bottom_right" don't represent an adress like "A1", they contain the value. You can't use them with "Range(".

Try this instead:

```
        Worksheets(3).Range(top_left.Address & ":" & bottom_right.Address).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed bottom_left was a typo I meant bottom_right! .Address with ":" and just a comma between the two ranges both work. :D